# Extract word uptill certain symbol

Tags: python, regex, findall

Hi I have this uniprot gff data that looks like

```
+--------+--------+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Entry  | check  | start | end  |                                               Domains                                               |
+--------+--------+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| O75581 | Repeat |    63 |  106 |  Note=LDL-receptor class B 1                                                                         |
| O75581 | Repeat |   150 |  193 |  Note=LDL-receptor class B 3                                                                         |
| O75581 | Domain |   282 |  324 |  Note=EGF-like 1                                                                                     |
| O75581 | Domain |  1248 | 1286 |  Note=LDL-receptor class A 1;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255|PROSITE-ProRule:PRU00124 |
| O75581 | Domain |  1287 | 1323 |  Note=LDL-receptor class A 2;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255|PROSITE-ProRule:PRU00124 |
| O75581 | Domain |  1325 | 1361 |  Note=LDL-receptor class A 3;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255|PROSITE-ProRule:PRU00124 |
| P13688 | Domain |    35 |  142 |  Note=Ig-like V-type;Ontology_term=ECO:0000250;evidence=ECO:0000250|UniProtKB:P31997                 |
| P13688 | Domain |   145 |  232 |  Note=Ig-like C2-type 1;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255|PROSITE-ProRule:PRU00114      |
| P13688 | Domain |   237 |  317 |  Note=Ig-like C2-type 2;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255|PROSITE-ProRule:PRU00114      |
| P13688 | Domain |   323 |  413 |  Note=Ig-like C2-type 3;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255|PROSITE-ProRule:PRU00114      |
| P19022 | Domain |   160 |  267 |  Note=Cadherin 1;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255|PROSITE-ProRule:PRU00043             |
| P19022 | Domain |   268 |  382 |  Note=Cadherin 2;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255|PROSITE-ProRule:PRU00043             |
| P19022 | Domain |   383 |  497 |  Note=Cadherin 3;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255|PROSITE-ProRule:PRU00043             |
| Q13586 | Domain |   132 |  200 |  Note=SAM;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255|PROSITE-ProRule:PRU00184                    |
| P04629 | Repeat |    90 |  113 |  Note=LRR 1                                                                                          |
| P04629 | Repeat |   116 |  137 |  Note=LRR 2                                                                                          |
+--------+--------+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to extract the domain names column `df['Domains]`. With the following code, I am close to getting the first 2 3 words of the domain name but doesn't work universally.

```
for row in df['Domains']:
    print(re.findall(r'Note=(\w*)(.?)(\w*)', row))
```

which gives something like this

```
[('LDL', '-', 'receptor')]
[('LDL', '-', 'receptor')]
[('EGF', '-', 'like')]
[('Ig', '-', 'like')]
[('Ig', '-', 'like')]`
```

So, I wish to change my approach and get everything starting after `Note=` and ends before `;` or end of line. How may I get this?

Comment: Note you should use vectorized Pandas methods if they exist, in this case, `Series.str.findall` is what you need.

Comment: Not applicable here

Comment: Quite is, `df['Domains'].str.findall(r'Note=([^;]*)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
for row in df['Domains']:
    print(re.findall(r'Note=([^;]*)', row))
```

Comment: Thanks! `re.findall(r'Note=([^;]*)' ` worked for me as I was trying to exclude Note =

Comment: @Kay, I believe this should remove Note=, I checked it with one line input, since I am not sure how did you created df, it worked fine for me.

Comment: DOWN VOTER, please do mention the reason for down vote here.

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in df['Domains']:
    phrase = re.findall('.*;', row)
    if len(phrase) > 0:
        print(phrase[0])
    else:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Greedy version:

(?:Note=).*(?:;)

None Greedy version:

(?:Note=).*?(?:;)

Match 'Note=' but does not capture it. Match and capture all other characters until you get to a semicolon. Match the semicolon but do not capture it.

Greedy version captures until the last semicolon.

None greedy version captures until the first semicolon.